# How to fix position of an element?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout-weight

I set the location of the ScrollView where it should be by using layout_weight, but the problem is, that Ill add elements in it later, and the ScrollView expands in size so it changes position, I need it to expand only to the bottom, but it expands to the top too. So i need to fix it so it wont expand at the top. I tried to use direct sizes in dp instead of weight, but I need it to look circa the same at different resolutions. Maybe there are some other ways how to solve the problem, without using layout_height, so thank you for your advices. Heres the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/chose1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/space"
    >
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="13"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: is there any use of the button with height 2dp?

Comment: yes, its part of a design

Comment: Proper way of doing this is just simply display the scrollview below the top views. Don't do hardcore dp and weight.  BTW what  is the view above scroll view?

Comment: The view above scroll view works as a marginTop, because I need to keep exactly distance between the button and scroll view. The problem is that I dont know how to do this possitioning by usuall way (if there is any), so I tried this, and possition is ok till i start adding elements in the layout in the scroll view. So maybe there is way to just fix the position, so it wont expand to the top, but only to the bottom.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is in your Linear Layout inside Scroll view is wrap_content and it will grow as you start adding content in Scroll View.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/recipes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Yeah setting height or margin works, but only for one resolution, thats why Im using weight there. But it gave me an idea to play with the heights, so in the end I set the height of the linear layout inside of the scroll view to match parent, and it works perfectly, the scroll view doesnt expand to the top now.

Answer (score 0):

For a sample , try adding more buttons in the linear layout in the scroll view and check if this is what you wanted.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to keep the exact space between all of this, so I used the layout_weight for it. When the scroll view is empty, the design looks well on each resolution, but when I add some elements in the scroll view, it expands not only to the bottom, but also to the top, and thats the problem. So I need to keep an exact space between top and the scroll view, and I dont want to do this by margins, because I need it to be equal on each resulution.

Comment: can you post a picture of your expected layout

Comment: I set the height of the linear layout inside of the scroll view to match parent and it works, the scroll view now expands only to the bottom, thats what I wanted.